# Откуда можно получить курс bitcoin в json формате?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Не могу найти куда посылать ajax запрос со значениями *тип валюты* *единицы* и получить в ответ сколько это будет btc
желательно в json формате

Comment: json - формат...

Comment: изменила, может Я что то не понимаю, но вроде jsonp выгоднее так как прокси не нужен. Разве нет?

Comment: Анна, прокси тут не при чём. Вам нужен сервис, который явно разрешает кросс-доменные запросы. jsonp к этому не имеет отношения.

Comment: jsonp - позволяет без указания Origin в заголовке делать запросы на разные домены

Comment: Да, только если у вас есть сервис, который возвращает jsonp. Если сервис не может прописать заголовоки для разрешения кросс-доменных ajax запросов, я бы не надеялся, что они хотя бы думали про jsonp...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker

UPD

http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json

Последняя предпочтительней, но возвращает много данных

В той же документации была ссылка. Внимательно посмотрите [тут](https://blockchain.info/ru/api/exchange_rates_api)

Comment: вычисляйте средствами JavaScript на основе курса BTC к нужной валюте, полученной по ссылке выше.

Comment: а так Я уже использовала их сервис
https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=343
но так и не смогла получит строку через ajax
искала то что Вы прислали на сайте https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-documentation
но так и не нашла
А это официальная дока то что Вы кинули?

Comment: Это документация к сервису blockchain.info на котором расположена некоторая статистика. Ручаться за нее не могу, стоит проверить данные.

Comment: а вот у меня был вопрос по поводу ajax как раз с этого сервиса
там ссылка ниже на https://blockchain.info/ru/tobtc
можно как то получить данные через прокси? потому что юзали рокси всё равно выдавал No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: ajax-запросы сервис не поддерживает, так что не является ответом

Comment: Да, вы правы, возникает ошибка.

Comment: Поправил ответ. Надеюсь поможет автору больше

Comment: @GrayHoax помог только https://bitpay.com/api/rates